# Asp.net MVC Razor rendering content from view without reloading layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have been asked to *fix* an MVC solution that has a single layout with many elements. It relies on an HTML template [Ublod - Responsive Admin Dashboard Template](https://coderthemes.com/ubold/layouts/old/light/index.html).
What I have is the result of different previous developers that have worked on their own with no collaboration, and now I'm supposed to solve a few issues but I'm tied up to what I have andcan't re-write everything.
One of the problems I have is that authentication is verified in the shared **_Layout** and there was a dynamic sidemenu (based on profiles in db) in a PartialView. The Layout has also a topbar that differs on profiles.
First thing I've done was to put the sidemenu and the topbar in the main _Layout, just to have authentication and profiling run only once instead of three times.
The home page is different from all the other and does not depend on controller (at the moment), all the other views are based on the same "page-starte.html" in the template.
Whenever I trigger an action the complete page is reloaded and the side menu loses the focus.
I have tried to go through Ajax and update only the div that contains the content, but I'm missing something.
I've tried with sections and PartialViews, but I must have done something wrong.
I need to update only the content without reloading the complete page.
Here is the _Layout:

```
        @{
        string cdnHost = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["web:cdnHost"];


        var profile = FIRMS_App.Context.UserContext.GetLoggedUser();

        var conteggioAttivitaUtenteNormale = profile.UtenteAttivita.Where(a => a.IdUtenteA == profile.Id && a.flagLetto == false).Select<FIRMS_App.UtenteAttivita, FIRMS_App.Attivita>(x => x.Attivita).Where(x => !x.Task).Count();
        var conteggioAttivitaUtenteAdmin = profile.UtenteAttivita.Where(a => a.flagLetto == false).Select<FIRMS_App.UtenteAttivita, FIRMS_App.Attivita>(x => x.Attivita).Where(x => !x.Task && x.IdAzienda == profile.IdAzienda).Count();

        var conteggioTaskUtenteNormale = profile.UtenteAttivita.Where(a => a.IdUtenteA == profile.Id && a.flagLetto == false && a.idStatoAttivita == 2).Count();
        var conteggioTaskUtenteAdmin = profile.UtenteAttivita.Where(a => a.flagLetto == false && a.idStatoAttivita == 2 && a.Attivita.IdAzienda == profile.IdAzienda).Count();
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="A fully featured admin theme which can be used to build CRM, CMS, etc.">
        <meta name="author" content="Coderthemes">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/images/favicon.ico">

        <!-- Plugin Css-->


        <title>Firms App - @ViewBag.Title</title>
        @* @Html.Partial("/firms-web/Views/Shared/_ScriptView.cshtml")*@
        <script src="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/plugins/bootstrap-table/css/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/Scripts/Main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/plugins/magnific-popup/css/magnific-popup.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/plugins/jquery-datatables-editable/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />

        <style>
            /*multi-select.css*/
            .ms-container {
                background: /*transparent*/ url('/assets/plugins/multiselect/img/switch.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .label {
                height: 35px;
                font-size: small;
                font-weight: normal;
                vertical-align: middle;
                line-height: 35px;
                padding-top: 0;
                padding-bottom: 0;
            }
        </style>

        @if (TempData["Result"] == "_OK")
        {
            if (TempData["View"] == "") { TempData["View"] = "Lista"; }

            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function () {
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        swal({
                            title: "<i class='i icon-like'></i>", text: "Operazione avvenuta con successo", type: "success"
                        })
                            .then(function () {
                                window.location.href = TempData["View"];//"Lista";
                            });
                    });
                };
            </script>
        }

        @if (TempData["Result"] == "_KO")
        {
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function () {
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        swal({
                            title: "<i class='i icon-dislike'></i><br>Operazione fallita", text: "@TempData["Message"]", type: "error"
                        })
                            .then(function () {
                                // window.location.href = "New";
                            });
                    });
                };
            </script>        
        }

        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    MainJS.init();
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body class="fixed-left">

        <!-- Begin page -->
        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Top Bar Start -->
            <div class="topbar">

                <!-- LOGO -->

                <div class="topbar-left">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <!-- <a href="index.html" class="logo"><i class="icon-magnet icon-c-logo"></i><span>Ub<i class="md md-album"></i>ld</span></a> -->
                        <!-- Image Logo here -->
                        <a href="/Home/Index" class="logo">
                            <!--<i class="icon-c-logo"> <img src="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/images/logo_sm.png" height="42"/> </i>-->
                            <!--<span><img src="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/images/logo_light.png" height="20"/></span>-->
                            <span>
                                <img src="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/images/savone_logo_160x35.png" height="35" /></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Button mobile view to collapse sidebar menu -->
                <nav class="navbar-custom">

                    <ul class="list-inline float-right mb-0">

                        <li class="list-inline-item notification-list">
                            <a class="nav-link waves-light waves-effect" href="#" id="btn-fullscreen">
                                <i class="dripicons-expand noti-icon"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        @* --- Redirect to Lista Task --- Start --- *@

                        <li class="list-inline-item notification-list">
                            <a class="nav-link right-bar-toggle waves-light waves-effect" href="@Url.Action("Lista", "Task")">
                                <i class="dripicons-bell noti-icon"></i>
                                @if (profile.SystemAdmin == false)
                                {
                                    <span class="badge badge-pink noti-icon-badge">@conteggioAttivitaUtenteNormale</span>}
                                else
                                {<span class="badge badge-pink noti-icon-badge">@conteggioAttivitaUtenteAdmin</span>}
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        @* --- Redirect to Lista Task --- End --- *@

                        @* --- Redirect to Lista Messaggi --- Start --- *@

                        <li class="list-inline-item notification-list">
                            <a class="nav-link right-bar-toggle waves-light waves-effect" href="@Url.Action("Lista", "Messaggi")">
                                @if (profile.SystemAdmin == true)
                                {
                                    <i class="dripicons-message noti-icon">@conteggioTaskUtenteAdmin</i>
                                }
                                @if (profile.SystemAdmin == false)
                                {
                                    <i class="dripicons-message noti-icon">@conteggioTaskUtenteNormale</i>
                                }
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        @* --- Redirect to Lista Messaggi --- End --- *@

                        <li class="list-inline-item dropdown notification-list">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light nav-user" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button"
                                aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false">
                                <img src="@profile.Avatar" alt="" class="thumb-md rounded-circle">>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right profile-dropdown " aria-labelledby="Preview">
                                <!-- item-->
                                <div class="dropdown-item noti-title">
                                    <h5 class="text-overflow"><small>@Html.Raw(profile.Nome + " " + profile.Cognome)</small> </h5>
                                </div>
                                @*@if (profile.SystemAdmin == true)
                                    {
                                        <!-- item-->
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item notify-item">
                                            <i class="md md-lock-open"></i> <span>Seleziona Azienda</span>
                                        </a>
                                    }*@
                                <!-- item-->
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Account")" class="dropdown-item notify-item">
                                    <i class="md md-settings-power"></i><span>Logout</span>
                                </a>

                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                    <ul class="list-inline menu-left mb-0">
                        <li class="float-left">
                            <button class="button-menu-mobile open-left waves-light waves-effect">
                                <i class="dripicons-menu"></i>
                            </button>
                        </li>
                        <li class="hide-phone app-search">
                            <!--   <form role="search" class="">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
                                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                </form>-->
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </nav>

            </div>
            <!-- Top Bar End -->


            <!-- ========== Left Sidebar Start ========== -->


            <div class="left side-menu">
                <div class="sidebar-inner slimscrollleft">
                    <div class="user-details">
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <img src="@Html.Raw(profile.Avatar)" alt="" class="thumb-md rounded-circle">
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-info">
                            @*@if (profile.Username == "owner@firms.com") {

                                     <div>@Html.Display(nomeAzienda)</div>

                                     }*@
                            <div class="dropdown">

                                @if (profile.Username == "owner@firms.com" && profile.IdAzienda != Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))
                                {
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">@Html.Raw(profile.Nome + " " + profile.Cognome + " dell'azienda " + profile.Aziende.Azienda)<span class="caret"></span></a>}

                                else
                                {<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">@Html.Raw(profile.Nome + " " + profile.Cognome)<span class="caret"></span></a>}
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
                                    @* @if (profile.SystemAdmin == true)
                                        {
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="md md-settings-power"></i> Seleziona Azienda</a>
                                        }*@
                                    @if (profile.Username == "owner@firms.com")
                                    {
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("SceltaAzienda", "CambiaAzienda")"><i class="md md-swap-vert-circle"></i>Cambia Azienda</a>
                                    }
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Account")"><i class="md md-settings-power"></i>Logout</a>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--- Divider -->
                    <div id="sidebar-menu">

                        @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && profile.Navigation != null)
                        {

                            <ul>
                                <li class="text-muted menu-title">Navigazione</li>
                                @{           
                            var main = profile.Navigation.Select(n => n.MenuPadre).Distinct().ToList();

                            if (profile.IdAzienda == Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))
                            {
                                main = main.Where(x => x.ToLower() == "azienda").ToList();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                main = main.Where(x => x.ToLower() != "azienda").ToList();
                            }

                            if (profile.Id == Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))
                            {
                                main = main.Where(x => x.ToLower() != "conversazioni" && x.ToLower() != "task").ToList();
                            }

                            for (var i = 0; i < main.Count; i++)
                            {
                                var menus = profile.Navigation.Where(n => n.MenuPadre == main[i]).ToList();

                                var menu = menus.FirstOrDefault();

                                    @Html.Raw("<li class='has_sub'>")
                                    @Html.Raw(" <a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='waves-effect'><i class='" + menu.Etichetta + "'></i> <span> " + menu.MenuPadre + " </span> <span class='menu-arrow'></span></a>")
                                    @Html.Raw("     <ul class='list-unstyled'>")    

                                foreach (var m in menus)
                                {
                                    @Html.Raw("         <li>" + @Html.ActionLink(m.Menu, m.Action, m.Controller) + "</li>")  // ori


                                    //@Html.Raw("         <li><a class=\"dropdown-item\" href=\"" + @Url.Action(m.Menu,  m.Controller, new {@class="ajaxLink"}) + "\"></a></li>")
                                }

                                    @Html.Raw("     </ul>")
                                    @Html.Raw("</li>")  
                            }
                                }
                            </ul>
                        }

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Left Sidebar End -->
            @Html.Partial("/Views/Shared/_ScriptView.cshtml")


            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <!-- Start right Content here -->
            <!-- ============================================================== -->


            <div class="content-page">
                <!-- Start content -->
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="container-fluid">

                        @RenderBody()


                    </div>
                    <!-- container -->

                </div>
                <!-- content -->
            </div>


            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <!-- End Right content here -->
            <!-- ============================================================== -->


        </div>
        <!-- END wrapper -->




        @*    <footer class="footer text-right">
            &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - FIRMS App
        </footer>*@


    </body>
    </html>

    @*<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("a.ajaxLink").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // stop the default click behavior
                $('#pageContent').empty(); // clean the div
                $("#pageContent").load($(this).attr("href"));
            });
        });
    </script>*@


    @*    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var myLinkHref = $("a.ajaxLink").eq(0).attr("href"); //Load the link's content on document ready
            $("#pageContent").load(myLinkHref);
            $("a.ajaxLink").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#pageContent").load($(this).attr("href"));
            });

        });
    </script>*@


    @*$("#callLogs").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("callLogs", "YourControllerName")',
            success: function (response) {               
                 $("#container_inner_frame").html(response);
            }
            error: function () {
                 alert("error occured");
            }    
        });
    });*@
```

here is a sample view:

```
    @model FIRMS_App.Models.DTO.ListaConversazioniView
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Lista";
    //string cdnHost = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["web:cdnHost"];// ;
    string cdnHost = "http://localhost:48129";
}


<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Page-Title -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h4 class="page-title">Inbox</h4>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Conversazioni</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Lista Conversazioni</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <!-- Right Sidebar -->
            <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-8">

                @using (Html.BeginForm("Conversazioni", "Messaggi", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1", name = "form1" }))
                { @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.idAttivita, new { @id = "selectedItemId" });
                    <div class="card-box p-1 m-t-20">
                        <div class="panel-body p-0">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-hover mails m-0">


                                    <tbody>

                                        @{string nome = "";
                                        }
                                        @if (Model.listaAttivita.Count() > 0)
                                        {
                                            foreach (var item in Model.listaAttivita.OrderBy(x => x.attivita.ModifiedDate).OrderBy(x => x.flagLetto))
                                            {

                                                if (nome != item.attivita.Oggetto)
                                                {
                                                    var clazz = "";
                                                    if (!item.flagLetto)
                                                    {
                                                        clazz = "unread";
                                                    }

                                            <tr class="@clazz">
                                                <td class="mail-select">
                                                    @*                                                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary m-r-15">
                                                        <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
                                                        <label for="checkbox1"></label>
                                                    </div>*@

                                                    <i class="fa fa-star m-r-15 text-muted"></i>


                                                    @if (item.flagLetto == false)
                                                    {
                                                        <i class="fa fa-circle m-l-5 text-info"></i>
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    { <i class="fa fa-circle m-l-5 text-success"></i>}
                                                </td>

                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="#" onclick="MainJS.selectForAssocia('@item.attivita.Id', 'form1');" class="email-name">@item.NomeCreatore</a>
                                                </td>

                                                <td class="hidden-xs">
                                                    <a href="#" onclick="MainJS.selectForAssocia('@item.attivita.Id', 'form1');" class="email-msg">@item.attivita.Oggetto</a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="text-right">@item.attivita.CreatedDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToShortDateString()
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="text-right">@item.attivita.CreatedDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToShortTimeString()
                                                </td>




                                            </tr>    nome = item.attivita.Oggetto;
                                                }




                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {<div class="form-control" style="text-align: center">La cartella Inbox è vuota</div>}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- panel body -->
                    </div>
                }

                <!-- panel -->

            </div>
            <!-- end Col-9 -->

        </div>
        <!-- End row -->

    </div>
    <!-- container -->

</div>
<!-- content -->
```

and here is part of the relative controller:

```
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Lista()
    {
        Profile profile = FIRMS_App.Context.UserContext.GetLoggedUser();
        List<AttivitaLettura> listaMessaggi = new List<AttivitaLettura>();

        if (profile != null)
            listaMessaggi = this._attivitaService.GetListaAttivitaPerLettura(profile.IdAzienda).Where(x => !x.attivita.Task).ToList();

        ListaConversazioniView Model = new ListaConversazioniView();
        Model.listaAttivita = listaMessaggi;

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView("pView", Model);
        else
            return View(Model);
    }
```

ASP.Net is version 4.5

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

No help from Others in the forum, but at the end, I solved the issue in a non elegant way. Since what I know is .Net and C# I managed the thing directly in the Layout, even if I've Always been told that views and layouts should have as less code as possible.
I recovered the calling view from the url of the rebuilded page **Request.Path** and mapped it accroding to the source db with a switch/case. Here is the final result:

```
        @{
        string cdnHost = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["web:cdnHost"];


        var profile = FIRMS_App.Context.UserContext.GetLoggedUser();

        var conteggioAttivitaUtenteNormale = profile.UtenteAttivita.Where(a => a.IdUtenteA == profile.Id && a.flagLetto == false).Select<FIRMS_App.UtenteAttivita, FIRMS_App.Attivita>(x => x.Attivita).Where(x => !x.Task).Count();
        var conteggioAttivitaUtenteAdmin = profile.UtenteAttivita.Where(a => a.flagLetto == false).Select<FIRMS_App.UtenteAttivita, FIRMS_App.Attivita>(x => x.Attivita).Where(x => !x.Task && x.IdAzienda == profile.IdAzienda).Count();

        var conteggioTaskUtenteNormale = profile.UtenteAttivita.Where(a => a.IdUtenteA == profile.Id && a.flagLetto == false && a.idStatoAttivita == 2).Count();
        var conteggioTaskUtenteAdmin = profile.UtenteAttivita.Where(a => a.flagLetto == false && a.idStatoAttivita == 2 && a.Attivita.IdAzienda == profile.IdAzienda).Count();
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    @*<html>*@
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="A fully featured admin theme which can be used to build CRM, CMS, etc.">
        <meta name="author" content="Coderthemes">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/images/favicon.ico">

        <!-- Plugin Css-->


        <title>Firms App - @ViewBag.Title</title>
        @* @Html.Partial("/firms-web/Views/Shared/_ScriptView.cshtml")*@
        <script src="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/plugins/bootstrap-table/css/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/Scripts/Main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/plugins/magnific-popup/css/magnific-popup.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/plugins/jquery-datatables-editable/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />

        <style>
            /*multi-select.css*/
            .ms-container {
                background: /*transparent*/ url('/assets/plugins/multiselect/img/switch.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .label {
                height: 35px;
                font-size: small;
                font-weight: normal;
                vertical-align: middle;
                line-height: 35px;
                padding-top: 0;
                padding-bottom: 0;
            }
        </style>

        @if (TempData["Result"] == "_OK")
        {
            if (TempData["View"] == "") { TempData["View"] = "Lista"; }

            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function () {
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        swal({
                            title: "<i class='i icon-like'></i>", text: "Operazione avvenuta con successo", type: "success"
                        })
                            .then(function () {
                                window.location.href = TempData["View"];//"Lista";
                            });
                    });
                };
            </script>
        }

        @if (TempData["Result"] == "_KO")
        {
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function () {
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        swal({
                            title: "<i class='i icon-dislike'></i><br>Operazione fallita", text: "@TempData["Message"]", type: "error"
                        })
                            .then(function () {
                                // window.location.href = "New";
                            });
                    });
                };
            </script>        
        }

        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    MainJS.init();
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body class="fixed-left">

        <!-- Begin page -->
        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Top Bar Start -->
            <div class="topbar">

                <!-- LOGO -->

                <div class="topbar-left">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <!-- <a href="index.html" class="logo"><i class="icon-magnet icon-c-logo"></i><span>Ub<i class="md md-album"></i>ld</span></a> -->
                        <!-- Image Logo here -->
                        <a href="/Home/Index" class="logo">
                            <!--<i class="icon-c-logo"> <img src="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/images/logo_sm.png" height="42"/> </i>-->
                            <!--<span><img src="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/images/logo_light.png" height="20"/></span>-->
                            <span>
                                <img src="@Html.Raw(cdnHost)/assets/images/savone_logo_160x35.png" height="35" /></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Button mobile view to collapse sidebar menu -->
                <nav class="navbar-custom">

                    <ul class="list-inline float-right mb-0">

                        <li class="list-inline-item notification-list">
                            <a class="nav-link waves-light waves-effect" href="#" id="btn-fullscreen">
                                <i class="dripicons-expand noti-icon"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        @* --- Redirect to Lista Task --- Start --- *@

                        <li class="list-inline-item notification-list">
                            <a class="nav-link right-bar-toggle waves-light waves-effect" href="@Url.Action("Lista", "Task")">
                                <i class="dripicons-bell noti-icon"></i>
                                @if (profile.SystemAdmin == false)
                                {
                                    <span class="badge badge-pink noti-icon-badge">@conteggioAttivitaUtenteNormale</span>}
                                else
                                {<span class="badge badge-pink noti-icon-badge">@conteggioAttivitaUtenteAdmin</span>}
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        @* --- Redirect to Lista Task --- End --- *@

                        @* --- Redirect to Lista Messaggi --- Start --- *@

                        <li class="list-inline-item notification-list">
                            <a class="nav-link right-bar-toggle waves-light waves-effect" href="@Url.Action("Lista", "Messaggi")">
                                @if (profile.SystemAdmin == true)
                                {
                                    <i class="dripicons-message noti-icon">@conteggioTaskUtenteAdmin</i>
                                }
                                @if (profile.SystemAdmin == false)
                                {
                                    <i class="dripicons-message noti-icon">@conteggioTaskUtenteNormale</i>
                                }
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        @* --- Redirect to Lista Messaggi --- End --- *@

                        <li class="list-inline-item dropdown notification-list">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light nav-user" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button"
                                aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false">
                                <img src="@profile.Avatar" alt="" class="thumb-md rounded-circle">>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right profile-dropdown " aria-labelledby="Preview">
                                <!-- item-->
                                <div class="dropdown-item noti-title">
                                    <h5 class="text-overflow"><small>@Html.Raw(profile.Nome + " " + profile.Cognome)</small> </h5>
                                </div>
                                @*@if (profile.SystemAdmin == true)
                                    {
                                        <!-- item-->
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item notify-item">
                                            <i class="md md-lock-open"></i> <span>Seleziona Azienda</span>
                                        </a>
                                    }*@
                                <!-- item-->
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Account")" class="dropdown-item notify-item">
                                    <i class="md md-settings-power"></i><span>Logout</span>
                                </a>

                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                    <ul class="list-inline menu-left mb-0">
                        <li class="float-left">
                            <button class="button-menu-mobile open-left waves-light waves-effect">
                                <i class="dripicons-menu"></i>
                            </button>
                        </li>
                        <li class="hide-phone app-search">
                            <!--   <form role="search" class="">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
                                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                </form>-->
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </nav>

            </div>
            <!-- Top Bar End -->


            <!-- ========== Left Sidebar Start ========== -->


            <div class="left side-menu">
                <div class="sidebar-inner slimscrollleft">
                    <div class="user-details">
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <img src="@Html.Raw(profile.Avatar)" alt="" class="thumb-md rounded-circle">
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-info">
                            @*@if (profile.Username == "owner@firms.com") {

                                     <div>@Html.Display(nomeAzienda)</div>

                                     }*@
                            <div class="dropdown">

                                @if (profile.Username == "owner@firms.com" && profile.IdAzienda != Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))
                                {
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">@Html.Raw(profile.Nome + " " + profile.Cognome + " dell'azienda " + profile.Aziende.Azienda)<span class="caret"></span></a>}

                                else
                                {<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">@Html.Raw(profile.Nome + " " + profile.Cognome)<span class="caret"></span></a>}
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
                                    @* @if (profile.SystemAdmin == true)
                                        {
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="md md-settings-power"></i> Seleziona Azienda</a>
                                        }*@
                                    @if (profile.Username == "owner@firms.com")
                                    {
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("SceltaAzienda", "CambiaAzienda")"><i class="md md-swap-vert-circle"></i>Cambia Azienda</a>
                                    }
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Account")"><i class="md md-settings-power"></i>Logout</a>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--- Divider -->
                    <div id="sidebar-menu">

                        @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && profile.Navigation != null)
                        {

                            // set navigation menu to launcher

                            string[] navcfg = (Request.Path).Split(new char[] { '/' });
                            string padre = (navcfg[1] == "Messaggi" ? "Conversazioni" : navcfg[1]);
                            string mnu = navcfg[2];

                            switch (Request.Path)
                            {

                                case "/Aziende/Lista":
                                    mnu = "Lista Aziende";
                                    break;

                                case "/Aziende/New":
                                    mnu = "Nuova Azienda";
                                    break;

                                case "/Reparti/Lista":
                                    mnu = "Lista Reparti";
                                    break;

                                case "/Reparti/New":
                                    mnu = "Nuovo Reparto";
                                    break;

                                case "/Reparti/Associa":
                                    mnu = "Associa Reparto";
                                    break;

                                case "/Profili/Lista":
                                    mnu = "Lista Profili";
                                    break;

                                case "/Profili/New":
                                    mnu = "Nuovo Profilo";
                                    break;

                                case "/Utenti/Lista":
                                    mnu = "Lista Utenti";
                                    break;

                                case "/Utenti/New":
                                    mnu = "Nuovo Utente";
                                    break;

                                case "/Dispositivi/Lista":
                                    mnu = "Lista Dispositivi";
                                    break;

                                case "/Dispositivi/New":
                                    mnu = "Nuovo Dispositivo";
                                    break;

                                case "/Dispositivi/Tipi":
                                    mnu = "Tipi Dispositivo";
                                    break;

                                case "/Dispositivi/Associa":
                                    mnu = "Associa Dispositivo";
                                    break;

                                case "/Task/Lista":
                                    mnu = "Lista Task";
                                    break;

                                case "/Task/New":
                                    mnu = "Nuovo Task";
                                    break;

                                case "/Messaggi/Lista":
                                    mnu = "Lista Messaggi";
                                    break;

                                case "/Messaggi/New":
                                    mnu = "Nuovo Messaggio";
                                    break;

                                case "/Profili/Associa":
                                    mnu = "Associa Menu";
                                    break;

                                case "/Utenti/Associa":
                                    mnu = "Associa Profilo";
                                    break;

                                case "/Dispositivi/TipoNew":
                                    mnu = "Nuovo Tipo Dispositivo";
                                    break;

                                case "/Dispositivi/Riepilogo":
                                    mnu = "Riepilogo";
                                    break;

                                case "/Features/Features":
                                    mnu = "Features";
                                    break;

                                case "/Servizi/Servizi":
                                    mnu = "Chiama servizi";
                                    break;

                                case "/Log/Log":
                                    mnu = "Lista log";
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    mnu = "Index";
                                    break;
                            }                                  

                            <ul>
                                <li class="text-muted menu-title">Navigazione</li>
                          @{           
                            var main = profile.Navigation.Select(n => n.MenuPadre).Distinct().ToList();

                            if (profile.IdAzienda == Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))
                            {
                                main = main.Where(x => x.ToLower() == "azienda").ToList();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                main = main.Where(x => x.ToLower() != "azienda").ToList();
                            }

                            if (profile.Id == Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))
                            {
                                main = main.Where(x => x.ToLower() != "conversazioni" && x.ToLower() != "task").ToList();
                            }

                            for (var i = 0; i < main.Count; i++)
                            {
                                var menus = profile.Navigation.Where(n => n.MenuPadre == main[i]).ToList();

                                var menu = menus.FirstOrDefault();

                                    @Html.Raw("<li class='has_sub'>")



                                //@Html.Raw(" <a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='waves-effect'><i class='" + menu.Etichetta + "'></i> <span> " + menu.MenuPadre + " </span> <span class='menu-arrow'></span></a>")
                                //@Html.Raw("     <ul class='list-unstyled'>")    
                                if (menu.MenuPadre == padre.ToUpper())
                                {
                                    @Html.Raw(" <a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='waves-effect subdrop'><i class='" + menu.Etichetta + "'></i> <span> " + menu.MenuPadre + " </span> <span class='menu-arrow'></span></a>")
                                    @Html.Raw("     <ul style=\"display: block\" class='list-unstyled'>")
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    @Html.Raw(" <a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='waves-effect'><i class='" + menu.Etichetta + "'></i> <span> " + menu.MenuPadre + " </span> <span class='menu-arrow'></span></a>")
                                    @Html.Raw("     <ul class='list-unstyled'>")
                                }




                                //foreach (var m in menus)
                                //{
                                //    @Html.Raw("         <li>" + @Html.ActionLink(m.Menu, m.Action, m.Controller) + "</li>")  // ori
                                //}


                                foreach (var m in menus)
                                {
                                    if (m.Menu == mnu)
                                    {
                                    @Html.Raw("         <li class = 'active'>" + @Html.ActionLink(m.Menu, m.Action, m.Controller) + "</li>")
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                    @Html.Raw("         <li>" + @Html.ActionLink(m.Menu, m.Action, m.Controller) + "</li>")  // ori
                                    }
                                }

                                    @Html.Raw("     </ul>")
                                    @Html.Raw("</li>")  
                            }
                          }
                            </ul>
                        }

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Left Sidebar End -->
            @Html.Partial("/Views/Shared/_ScriptView.cshtml")


            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <!-- Start right Content here -->
            <!-- ============================================================== -->


            <div class="content-page">
                <!-- Start content -->
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="container-fluid">

                        @RenderBody()


                    </div>
                    <!-- container -->

                </div>
                <!-- content -->
            </div>


            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <!-- End Right content here -->
            <!-- ============================================================== -->


        </div>
        <!-- END wrapper -->




        @*    <footer class="footer text-right">
            &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - FIRMS App
        </footer>*@


    </body>
    @*</html>*@
```